# What is the best way to export modules with submodules in (Vue, React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, web-component

What is the best way to export a module that includes submodules using an `index.js`. For a long time now I follow a pattern on naming and saving my web components on my projects (Vue or React). But I want a more practical way to export a module using a single index to avoid cases like the following:

**My Pattern**

```
import PostDetail from 'src/views/posts/PostDetail'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `react` and `redux` for my applications. We mostly try to follow modular design in code folder structure.

Modules happen to be independent in itself and can be used standalone. If some parts of modules are required to be used outside the module itself, we only expose those files through it's `index.js`

Here's what we follow:

```
Project-name
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── components
│       ├── misc
│       ├── objects
│       └── vendor
├── build
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
├── src
│   ├── modules
│   │   │  
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   ├── actions
│   │   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── helpers
│   │   │   └── reducers
│   │   ├── module_1
│   │   │   ├── sub_module_1
│   │   │   │   ├── actions
│   │   │   │   ├── components
│   │   │   │   │   └── body
│   │   │   │   ├── helpers
│   │   │   │   └── reducers
│   │   │   └── sub_module_2
│   │   │       ├── actions
│   │   │       ├── components
│   │   │       ├── helpers
│   │   │       └── reducers
│   │   ├── module_2
│   │   │   └── components
│   │   ├── module_3
│   │   │   ├── actions
│   │   │   ├── components
│   │   │   │   └── body
│   │   │   ├── helpers
│   │   │   └── reducers
│   │   └── module_4
│   │       ├── components
│   │       └── helpers
│   └── pages
├── stories
│   ├── common
│   ├── establishment
│   │   └── visiting_clinics
│   ├── providers
│   │   └── body
│   └── relations
└── tools
```

Each module has an `index.js` at it's root directory which exposes required files and functions which is to be used in other modules.

This structure makes local file interactions smooth as `imports` are short,  clearly visible and name spaced(functionality based) where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. I've had this same question in mind for a while and tried out a few different approaches and settled at one that seems to work pretty fine for me.

1. Put your reusable components in one place.
2. Put your layout wrappers that use the reusable components in one place.

**1. Reusable Components**

All your reusable components include custom buttons and standalone components like Posts as you've mentioned. If you're posts can have details and comments, keep two separate components `PostDetails` and `PostComments` and import and compose them in a separate `Post` component. ***Plug and play is the key.***. You can opt for two structures here,

`components/PostDetails`

`components/PostComments`

`components/Post`

or

`components/Post/PostDetails/...`

`components/Post/PostComments/...`

and import them in `components/Post/Post.js`

But your default export will be in `components/Post/index.js` that will export `Post.js`. This way you're making sure, Post component is composed and reusable and can be imported as `components/Post` in any page/layout.

**2. Layout Wrappers**

All your pages/layouts go here. Typical example would be home page, about page that would import the components and put them in the right place.

This usually goes like with folder names like pages or containers depending on the project.

`pages/home`

`pages/about`

I have a few code repos that can help you better grasp this project structure.

[Portfolio](https://github.com/flexdinesh/flexdinesh.github.io/tree/dev)

[React-Redux Boilerplate](https://github.com/flexdinesh/react-redux-boilerplate)